# Signalr Hub has been disposed

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am writing a multi player game and using SignalR to update the game table. I am receiving this error.

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SHHub'.'

The process works like this.  The user clicks the Join button and this code is run in the hub.

```
        MultiPlayer MultiPlayer = await DBService.GetMultiPlayerById(pMultiPlayerId, pPartitionKey);

        //Add connection to group
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, pMultiPlayerId);

        string oNickName = string.Empty;
        foreach (GamePlayer oPlayer in MultiPlayer.GamePlayers)
        {
            if (oPlayer.AppUserId == pAppUserID)
            {
                oNickName = oPlayer.NickName;
                oPlayer.Status = "Joined Game";
                break;
            }
        }
        
        List<string> PlayerRoster = new List<string>();
        List<bool> Joined = new List<bool>();
        foreach (GamePlayer oPlayer in MultiPlayer.GamePlayers)
        {
            if (oPlayer.PlayerType == "Player")
            {
                PlayerRoster.Add(oPlayer.NickName);
                if (oPlayer.Status == "Pending")
                {
                    Joined.Add(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    Joined.Add(true);
                }
            }
        }

        await DBService.SaveMultiPlayer(MultiPlayer);

        await Clients.Group(pMultiPlayerId).SendAsync("JoinedGame", $"{oNickName} has joined the game", PlayerRoster, Joined);
```

This code works everytime.  Next the user clicks the Start button.  This is the code that runs.

```
        MultiPlayer MultiPlayer = await DBService.GetMultiPlayerById(pMultiPlayerId, pPartitionKey);

        if (MultiPlayer.Status == "In Progress")
        {
            return;
        }

        MultiPlayer.Status = "In Progress";

        string oNickName = string.Empty;
        foreach (GamePlayer oPlayer in MultiPlayer.GamePlayers)
        {
            if (oPlayer.AppUserId == pAppUserID)
            {
                oNickName = oPlayer.NickName;
            }
            oPlayer.Status = "Playing";
        }

        await DBService.SaveMultiPlayer(MultiPlayer);

        await Clients.Group(pMultiPlayerId).SendAsync("StartedGame", $"{oNickName} has started the game");
```

The last statement generates the error listed above.  I am new to Signalr and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you tried to debug it or have checked the browser trace log? when exactly its been disposed?

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron
In the start button code listed above, the Clients object exists before the first line of code is executed. After execution, the Clients object does not exist.  This method - MultiPlayer MultiPlayer = await DBService.GetMultiPlayerById(pMultiPlayerId, pPartitionKey);  retrieves a record from an Azure Cosmos document database.

Comment: This happens when you capture the hub and try to use it past the invocation. Common ways this happens is when you Task.Run or spin up a new thread in a hub method and capture the Clients property.